Sorting Pivot Table high to low with lots of Data?
I have a pivot table in Excel that I cannot get to sort from High to Low on the "amount"
I tried making all data linear and "posting link" into another cell, but it still with not sort. Even with/without other filters.
Pivot Table 
What am i doing wrong?
I would like Sum of Amount to sort High to Low ($). I would not like to use Macros of VBA.

try convert the formatting from currency to simple number
